# What is the "initial screen" for displaying a journal's copyright?

Tags: journals, paper-submission, copyright, preprint

I submitted my first journal paper to IEEE today, and when I considered posting it on ArXiv just to be safe from scooping, I noticed that IEEE has a policy for submitted content, which does not mention anything about the paper being allowed on ArXiv after it has been submitted to IEEE.

But, since IEEE allows posting a submitted paper on institutional repositories etc. as long as the copyright notice is displayed, I'm assuming I can publish it on ArXiv too, since they may have accidentally ommitted mentioning it, thinking that everyone would first put their pre-print on ArXiv and only then submit to IEEE. They didn't expect someone like me to submit to IEEE and then put it on ArXiv. Even [TechRxiv's FAQ is ambiguous](https://www.techrxiv.org/f/faqs#faq-10). Although [IEEE's manual](https://pspb.ieee.org/images/files/files/opsmanual.pdf) on page 88 states:

> IEEE does not restrict the rights of authors to use their
>   IEEEcopyrighted articles in their own teaching, training, or work
>   responsibilities, or those of their institutions or employers. In any
>   preprint version archived by the author after submission, IEEE
>   requires that IEEE will be credited as copyright holder. Upon
>   publication of the work, authors are asked to include the article’s
>   Digital Object Identifier (DOI).

To put my paper on ArXiv or TechRxiv now, I'll have to follow IEEE's policy of "IEEE must be credited as the copyright holder with the following statement included on the initial screen displaying IEEE-copyrighted material:". **I don't understand what this "initial screen" is. Should I mention the copyright below the title of my paper or anywhere on the paper, as long as it is on the first page of the paper?**

ps: TechRxiv [mentions](https://www.techrxiv.org/f/submission-guidelines) "Includes permission to reuse previously published or copyrighted material, if applicable". Again, I'm assuming I can submit to TechRxiv if I mention the copyright on the first page?

Comment: Side note: IEEE does not have the copyright till it is transferred when the paper is accepted, right?

Comment: I think you've figured it out as well as it can be figured out.

Comment: @GoodDeeds That's the case in ComSoc, not sure about the rest of them though.

Answer (score 3):

IEEE support mentioned that the paper can be uploaded to arXiv even after submitting to IEEE as long as this information is added to the first page of the article:

“© 20XX IEEE.  Personal use of this material is permitted.  Permission from IEEE must be obtained for all other uses, in any current or future media, including reprinting/republishing this material for advertising or promotional purposes, creating new collective works, for resale or redistribution to servers or lists, or reuse of any copyrighted component of this work in other works.”

By "initial screen" they meant for it to appear on the first page someplace. They didn't want to require it to appear "bottom of the left column" or "under the byline" because different repositories can have different displays. They just need it to be at the beginning of the article.